# how to control child elements by onClick from parent in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

crafting basic app in react as following:

parent container receive state by ajax and contains four columns, left column - all messages items, second column message body (should be shown when message element is clicked as well as controls), next - message controls (next, prev) and action type:

[image: react app screeshot]

how to to properly attach a controls to children elements for instance for `onClick` to message element? here is the snippet of a parent:

```
var ModerationContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
      ...            
    },
    LoadMessagesFromApi: function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
        ... // loads messages from json api into state
        });
    },
    testor: function () {
        alert();
    },
    render: function () {
        var allMessageItems = this.state.data.map(function (message) {
            return (
                <MessageItem id={message.id} key={message.id} onClick={this.testor}/>
            );
        }, this);
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-md-2 messageColumn">
                    {allMessageItems}
                </div>
                <MessageBodyColumn/>
                <ControlsColumn />
                <BlockColumn />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

No onclick event is executed after i click message block althrought I attached `this` to `map` while rendering messages block, what did i wrong ?

Also, how it is possible to auto select first message item if none of them clicked ?

Any hints or links on tutorials from experienced with react people much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would right the `MessageItem` on the parent like

`<MessageItem key={message.id} onClick={this.testor.bind(this, message.id) }/>`

Then inside your `MessageItem` component you can take the onClick handler from the pros, lets say MessageItem is a `div` your render function could be like

```
render()
{
   const onClick = this.props.onClick;
   const label = `Message${this.props.key}`;

   return( <div onClick={ onClick }> { label }</div>)

}
```

and if you write your testor like

```
testor: function ( id ) {
    alert( id );
}
```

You can see the id of the clicked message.